# How to move vertical split window to horizontal split, when there is an existing horizontal split?

Tags: vim, window-management

In Vim I tend to open buffers in new vertical splits (with the occasional horizontal split). I keep my code to 80 chars wide, so this works pretty well on large monitors.

I often end up with this window arrangement:

```
---------------------
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
------    |  A |  B |
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
---------------------
```

At four or five columns wide, it can start getting a bit too narrow, so then I want to move the windows around so it looks like this:

```
----------------
|    |    |  A |
|    |    |    |
------    ------
|    |    |  B |
|    |    |    |
----------------
```

As far as I know, this is impossible to do by moving the windows in Vim.

The only way to get that window arrangement I've found, is to close window A, and then re-open A as a new horizontal split from window B.

Is that correct, or is there a way to move/re-arrange windows like that in Vim?  Maybe a plugin?

I'm yet to find anything, so I thought I would ask because I find the opening/closing of windows anoying and breaks my flow.

FWIW, I find the `Ctrl-W + J` / `Ctrl-W + K` shortcuts useless, because they make the new horizontal split as wide as the whole screen, rather than splitting with the neighbouring window.  I.e. `Ctrl-W + J` would give me this:

```
----------------
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
------    |  A |
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
----------------
|              |
|      B       |
----------------
```

Which is generally never what I want.

If anyone has some ideas, let me know!

Comment: I'd do like you: close and split. Would `set splitright set splitbelow` help?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin that can do exactly what you want. Here's the link : https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/suckless.vim.

Comment: Yes, it does have a shortcut for what I want. Cheers!